# How to ignore nested text in emails getting with Peeker checkin IMAP

Tags: php, email, imap

I have a ticket system where i get the emails using Peeker (checkin directly the IMAP):

https://sophistry.github.io/peeker/peeker_quickstart.html

What I do it's something like this:

```
 $email = $this->peeker->get_message($email_id);
 $emailbody = $purifier->purify($email);
```

Then the $emailbody it will be inserted on the database according to the [#ticket_token]

```
$ticket = ['message' = $emailbody,...]
Ticket::create($ticket);
```

The problem is that when we have crossed several emails, all the nested messages from any email manager are also included and turns the list into an aberration.

What I want is for only the main message to be inserted and any nested emails in the body of the email to be ignored. I have searched if there is any pattern or any element from which to cut even if they were different in gmail.com, outlook and other emails but I can't find the way.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There is no standard for this.  You can only do this heuristically; for example, those services all tend to  use some sort of CSS or HTML classes to mark off replies, so you’d have to use an HTML parser to pull them out, but every email client will do it differently.